# Remove conditionally "Proceed to checkout" button in WooCommerce cat page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I want to remove a button in cart display, when the rule is not respect.
I made a custom Php for check if the rule is on, and display butoon "proceed to checkout" when it's good and hide it when it's not but it still here when the rule is on or off, it's like "default button" display always and i don't know how to disable it
My php :

```
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    // Activation de la vente par multiple de 6
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
        array(
            'id' => '_product_multiple',
            'label' => __('Activation de la vente par multiple de 6', 'woocommerce')
        )
    );
    
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');

/* Permet de sauvegarder le champ multiple */
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id){
     function easy_field_woocommerce_product($post_id, $field_name){
        $woocommerce_product = $_POST[$field_name];
        if (isset($woocommerce_product))
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field_name, esc_html($woocommerce_product));
         else
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field_name, '');
    }
    easy_field_woocommerce_product($post_id, '_product_multiple');
}
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');




/* Permet de verifier si le panier est en erreur */
function validate_all_cart_contents(){
    $test = WC()->cart->get_cart();
    $total = 0;
    foreach($test as $t){
        $qty = $t['quantity'];
        $product_attr = get_post_meta( $t['product_id'], '_product_multiple' );
        if(!empty($product_attr[0])){
            $total = $total + $qty; 
        }
    }
    
    if($total > 0){
        for($i = 0; $i <= $total; $i+=6){}

        $testmultiple = $i - $total;
        
        if($testmultiple != 6){
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'Attention ! Vous ne pouvez pas valider votre commande tant que vous n\'avez pas choisi des bouteilles de 75cl par cartons de 6 bouteilles.<br/><br/>Vous avez actuellement '.$total.' bouteilles de 75cl en panier, vous devez encore en sélectionner '.$testmultiple.'.<br/><br/>-> Les bouteilles de 150cl (Magnum) ainsi que les verres & les caisses bois ne sont pas concernés, vous pouvez ajouter en panier n\'importe quelle quantité.' ), 'error' );
            
        } else {
            remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'validate_all_cart_contents');
```

I tried the way by the theme , by css custom.
maybe add a function to display:none ? idk

[when the rule is not respect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWIvH.png)
[when the rule is respect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUEcV.png)

Comment: So what your "when the rule is respect" screenshot there shows, is what exactly - are those _two_ checkout buttons now?

Comment: Yes, one that is displayed when the rule is true, and another "by default" that remains displayed. Maybe with a CSS selector I can disable it?

Comment: Why are you _adding_ the action in those two else branches? You remove the already existing action when your conditions are met - but if that is not the case, then the already existing action should _still_ exist, if you did not explicitly remove it elsewhere ...?

Comment: you suggest I remove the first " else {
     add_action('woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20);
}"?
but it does not solve my problem I tried and it does not deactivate the default button and the duplicate if the rule is respected
I'm not sure I understand the answer, I have the impression that comde code conflicts with a plugin or the wordpress theme

Comment: It wasn't an answer, merely a suggestion ... I can't tell if other plugins or the theme might somehow interfere with this, from the outside. You'd have to do some local debugging to find out.

Comment: Why don't you just do `if ($total %6 == 0)` to check if $total is divisible by 6 instead of the needlessly inefficient for loop?

Answer (score 0):

*Updated*

There are some mistakes in your code and inefficient complications. In the code below, I use JavaScript (jQuery) to hide the button:

```php
// Add a checkbox to product single pages settings
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_checkbox_product_multiple');
function add_checkbox_product_multiple() {
    global $product_object;

    $field_key = '_product_multiple';

    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';

    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(  array(
        'id'          => $field_key,
        'label'       => __('Vente par multiple de 6', 'woocommerce'),
        'description' => __('Activation de la Vente par multiple de 6', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'value'       => $product_object->get_meta($field_key) ? 'yes' : 'no',
    ) );
    
    echo '</div>';
}

// Save the checkbox setting value from product single pages
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_checkbox_product_multiple_value');
function save_checkbox_product_multiple_value( $product ) {
    $field_key = '_product_multiple';
    $product->update_meta_data($field_key, isset($_POST[$field_key]) ? '1' : '0');
}

// Validation for items having "Sales by 6" activated
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'custom_cart_contents_validation');
function custom_cart_contents_validation(){
    $total = 0;
    foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item){
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );

        if( $product->get_meta('_product_multiple') ){
            $total   += $item['quantity'];
        }
    }
    
    if( $total > 0 ){
        $multiple  = 6;
        $remainder = intval($total % $multiple);
        $remaining = intval($multiple - $remainder);

        if ( $remainder !== 0 ) {
            // Error notice
            $message = sprintf( __("Attention ! Vous ne pouvez pas valider votre commande tant que vous n'avez pas choisi de bouteilles de 75cl par cartons de %s bouteilles.", "woocommerce"), $multiple) . '<br/><br/>' .
            sprintf( __("Vous avez actuellement %s bouteilles de 75cl en panier, vous devez encore en sélectionner %s", "woocommerce"), $total, $remaining) . '<br/><br/>' .
            __("Les bouteilles de 150cl (Magnum) ainsi que les verres & les caisses bois ne sont pas concernés, vous pouvez ajouter en panier n'importe quelle quantité.", "woocommerce");

            wc_clear_notices(); // Remove other notices
            wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' ); // Output error message

            // jQuery: Hide "proceed to checkout" button
            ?><script>jQuery(function($){ $('.wc-proceed-to-checkout').hide();});</script><?php
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and work.

Comment: I tried and nothing to do, I share with you my whole code of my function file that I made for my child theme

Comment: I edit my question post with my complete code, I had to do some tinkering for the button not to appear twice

Comment: @RomainYouaabed Bon bon :) … I have updated my code. It should work for you, too. Try to deactivate / activate back (and save) the checkbox on the products (you sell by 6) that you are going to test.